# Jolt:: Number of files count and list out the files based source

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

Number of files count and list out the files based source.

**Input** :

```json
[
  {
    "filename": "FF/raw/first/raw_A/filenameA_20240212002113.DAT"
  },
  {
    "filename": "FF/raw/first/raw_A/filenameA__20240205150101.DAT"
  },
  {
    "filename": "FF/raw/first/raw_B/filenameB_20240212002113.DAT"
  },
  {
    "filename": "FF/raw/first/raw_B/filenameB_20240205150101.DAT"
  }
]
```

**Expected output** :

```json
[
  {
    "Source": "raw_A",
    "Filecount": 2,// Number of files that indicates in fileNames
    "FileName": [
      "filenameA_20240212002113.DAT",
      "filenameA_20240205150101.DAT"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Source": "raw_B",
    "Filecount": 2,
    "FileName": [
      "filenameB_20240212002113.DAT",
      "filenameB_20240205150101.DAT"
    ]
  }
]
```

What I have tried in **jolt spec** :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*/*/*/*/*": "Source:&(0,4):filecount:: Filename.&(0,5)" // extract the leaf node by using 5th asterisk, eg. use &(0,5)
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "$": "&2.[#2]"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "Filecount": "=size(@(1,&filename))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[#2].&1"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: @Barbaros Özhan see if am anything missing to get the counts and help me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following transformation

```json
[
  { // group objects by raw_A & B
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*/*/*/*/*": {
            "$(0,5)": "&(1,4).FileName[]"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // calculate the lengths of "FileName" arrays
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "Filecount": "=size(@(1,FileName))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "$": "[#2].Source", // convert values of object keys to an attribute's values 
        "*": "[#2].&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the **demo** on the site https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

Comment: wonderful.Thank you @Barbaros Özhan.   .I just updated when we get single file the count is mismatching , since those file not added as array format. Hence In Shift i just added  
"$(0,5)": "&(1,4).FileName.[]" to make an array and then get the count.

Comment: you're right @ManimaranDhandapani exactly, I've added those square brackets as well.